# How to build a syncadapter for the google calendar?

Tags: android, calendar, synchronization, google-calendar-api, android-syncadapter

I'm building an application for students to manage the courses of a university.

Now I would like to synchronize the events (an event has a date and time and a brief description) with the google calendar of Android.

I took a look at the samplesync adapter from the Android sample, but I didn't find it very useful for the calendar.

The sync of the app should be enabled and disabled from the settings of the app with a checkbox.

Does anyone has some sample code that can be useful??

Answer (score 0):

1. Use `android.preference.PreferenceActivity` to make your preference page.
2. Ensure that your app updates the checkbox on the preference page with the value from the system before it opens.  (The setting may have been changed in the Accounts & Sync system control panel.)  Use `ContentResolver.getSyncAutomatically(Account account, String authority)` to read the system value
3. Command the system to match the PreferenceActivity setting using `ContentResolver.setSyncAutomatically(Account account, String authority, boolean sync)` --

Note that you can't control sync on a provider -- you control it for an account/provider pair.  Your app will need to keep a copy of the Account it is set to use so it can pass it in these calls.

Comment: Hi I am trying but I got some issue.like only proviver may write to access calandar access level.could you please guide me how can I do that

Comment: @Maid786: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/providers/calendar-provider.html#manifest