# How can i fetch data in google calendar api in Calendar view?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, google-calendar-api

How can I make this data I fetch in google calendar API in Calendar View using Android Studio? And how I keep it synchronized?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use [Calendar View](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/CalendarView.html), then try to check these tutorials that can show you on how to use it with Android code. You can follow the step by step procedure here with sample code that you can copy.

- [CalendarView Example: How to use Android Calendar View Widget](http://www.viralandroid.com/2015/11/android-calendarview-example.html)
- [CompactCalendarView](https://github.com/SundeepK/CompactCalendarView)
- [Android Calendarview Example](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/widget/android-calendarview-example/)

Comment: I can do that but my problem is syncing this data/events to my calendar view?

Comment: My problem is how can i sync those data in my Calendar View?

Answer (score 0):

You can have different solutions for sync your events in the Calendar View.

One of them is just making the user refreshing your app using something like [Swipe-to-Refresh interface pattern](https://developer.android.com/training/swipe/add-swipe-interface.html).

Other solutions are running the request to the API whenever the user opens the application inside activities lifecycle methods, [running a service](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/services.html) or using a [sync adapter](https://developer.android.com/training/sync-adapters/creating-sync-adapter.html).

Important to read: [Google Calendar API: Synchronize Resources Efficiently](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/calendar/v3/sync)

Other questions:

[Android Calendar: how to write sync adapter for calendar INSERT](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16360073/android-calendar-how-to-write-sync-adapter-for-calendar-insert)

[How to build a syncadapter for the google calendar?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6004255/how-to-build-a-syncadapter-for-the-google-calendar)