# how to use google calendar api into a custom calendar and how can get events into a custom calendar?

Tags: android, google-calendar-api

I need to google calendar API sync. without use custom calendar and how to get google API link and how to write code.i need to direct access google calendar by any google application.

Comment: may be thsi will help you:- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544878/how-can-i-data-i-fetch-in-google-calendar-api-in-calendar-view

Comment: "_how_ _to_ _get_ _google_ _API_ _link_ _and_ _how_ _to_ _write_ _code_" I would start checking google doc and tutorials. Onece done I would try it myself and if I found a problem I would [mcve]

Comment: i am already use it but i need show events show in calendar view.

Answer (score 1):

Check below examples
Here is the dependency add into your build.gradle file

```
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:6.5.87'
    compile 'com.google.apis:google-api-services-calendar:v3-rev119-1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-android:1.19.1'
    compile 'com.google.api-client:google-api-client-gson:1.19.1'
```

Now open your AndroidManifest.xml file and add the following code right after the manifest tag.

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.GET_ACCOUNTS" />
```

And add the following code right before closing the application tag:

```
<meta-data
    android:name="com.google.android.gms.version"
    android:value="@integer/google_play_services_version" />
```

Hope this may help you: [Link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42544878/how-can-i-data-i-fetch-in-google-calendar-api-in-calendar-view) 
& this is a [Demo Example :](https://github.com/miguelarauj1o/CalendarQuickStart)